# Intel and AMD graphics on 16.04

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, radeon, 16.04, amd-graphics

When I try to experiment 16.04 in live mode, I have a problem: the Xorg just crashes. I have a integrated Intel card and a AMD R7.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

And

```
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360]
```

This happen:

[image: Error image]

Someone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I "solve" it.

Option 1: boot in UEFI mode (normally, I don't use UEFI). I don't know why, this way the Xorg doesn't broke.

Option 2: installing directly, without use in live mode. Frustrating, but it work too.

Now, just rest to me wait a driver, because I'm using the onboard Intel graphic card.

Comment: Managed to use the Topaz XT yet? I have a similar laptop and can only use the integrated i5 with 16.04...